# What is href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','b3')">

Tags: c#, javascript, webbrowser-control, visual-c#-express-2010

I am coding a web browser control application that will perform some specific operations in a website.

There are, however, a couple pages of tables in the website, where transition in between is implemented with a Java Script command. Here is what I get when I use inspect element over one of the transition buttons:

```
<a class="ctl00_cph1_mnuPager_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','b2')"> 2 </a>
```

Given that I have already have the page in my c# application as follows:

```
HTMLDOCUMENT BrowserContent = webBrowser1.Document;
```

Can you give me any tips about how to programmatically click on that page transition button(ie. call that script).
I tried:

```
BrowserContent.InvokeScript("javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','b2')");
```

But it didn't help.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Answer was simply

BrowserContent.InvokeScript("javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','2')");

somehow Google Chrome returned b2 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
BrowserContent.InvokeScript("javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cph1$mnuPager','2')")‌​;
```

This will invoke the script inside the double quotes.